# Solving for Y, Linear and Conic Convergence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

In casual mathematics solving for x, y, z, etc... is usually pretty simple. With the very seemingly basic math that I know, I come across some equations that I cannot figure out myself. In this specific case, I am trying to solve for $y$.
$$
-\sqrt{-\left(\left(y-\left(W_{heely2}\right)\right)^{2}-\left(F_{orks}\frac{1}{25.4}\right)^{2}\right)}=\frac{y-\left(W_{heely2}\right)}{\tan\left(-\frac{H_{eadtubeangle}}{\frac{180}{\pi}}\right)}
$$
In my previous question, subscripts were somewhat confusing without an explanation, but to be clear, the subscript doesn't change anything.... so for example $W_{heely2}$ in mathematical terms is just a variable like $x$ or $y$. This is the same for $F_{orks}$, $W_{heelx2}$, and $H_{eadtubeangle}$. 

This equation is a solution to where a line intersects a circle (might be called a conic section, I hope this is right) outputting a $y$ value. I tried solving for $y$ but I kept getting stuck with $y$ being on both sides, and every time I tried to move it to one side, it affected the $y$ on the opposite side and I couldn't get $y$ by itself.

Comment: As a simple starter suggestion, try not to use unwieldy subscripts, and when you can get rid of conversions, do that as well. Note also that the addition portion on both sides cancels out; hence we could more reasonably write your equation as: $$\sqrt{f^2+2wy-y^2-w^2}=\frac{w-y}{tan(-\alpha)}$$where $f$ is now in cm, $\alpha$ is in radians, and we've removed two variables entirely. Now square both sides and see if you can't get a solution more readily; the quadratic equation will be useful.

Comment: Okay, I did this and ended up with two equations (which is normal) here they are:   $$f=w\csc\left(a\right)-y\csc\left(a\right)$$ and $$f=-w\csc\left(a\right)-y\csc\left(a\right)$$

Comment: I assume to solve for $y$ you would end up with: $$y=\frac{w\csc\left(a\right)-f}{\csc\left(a\right)}$$ and $$y=\frac{-w\csc\left(a\right)-f}{\csc\left(a\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\frac{W_{heely2}\csc\left(-\frac{H_{eadtubeangle}}{\frac{180}{\pi}}\right)-F_{orks}\frac{1}{25.4}}{\csc\left(-\frac{H_{eadtubeangle}}{\frac{180}{\pi}}\right)}$$